# How can an airflow task know if it is executed via the airflow test cli command?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

In our company, our airflow users would like to test some tasks locally before they push to production. In particular, we have tasks that will run SQL queries in our data warehouse and users will want to check the output of those queries.

Is it possible for the task to know that it is being executed from the test cli command rather than from the normal run? Based on this we would like to tweak our SQL queries to export the data to different tables.

I suppose I could pass a parameter in the command line. For example:

```
airflow tasks test dag_id task_id executation_date -t {"test":true}
```

But is there a built-in way that does not require additional input from the user?

I searched in the documentation but did not find anything specific. The workaround of passing an extra parameter could work but there is a risk that the user forgets to add it.

Comment: you can change the default , so in case the user does not sent this param it is a test. this way, only in production you would only need to add it.

Comment: thanks @ozs that could work indeed. I wish there was something more integrated though!